# Invalid Date returned by day.js in Firefox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, firefox, dayjs

I am having a date in the format 2022-01-27 09:23:48 UTC and I am parsing the date into MMMM-DD-YYYY format (Jan-27-2022) using [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) .Its working fine in chrome but firefox is returning Invalid.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs"

const utcDate = '2022-01-27 09:23:48 UTC'
const formatedDate = dayjs(utcDate).format("MMMM-DD-YYYY")
```

I have also tried the customParseFormat mentioned in the docs and some other threads

```
import dayjs from "dayjs"
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)

const utcDate = '2022-01-27 09:23:48 UTC'
const formatedDate = dayjs(utcDate, 'MMMM-DD-YYYY')
```

In both cases its returning 'Invalid Date' in firefox and safari but working fine in chrome. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: I can reproduce but it is fixed by  providing a valid ISO8601 date string (or providing a format pattern to `dayjs` (you have to take off the UTC)  `dayjs(utcDate.slice(0, -4), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format("MMMM-DD-YYYY")`

Comment: Your input string doesn't match the ISO8601 format, and none of the [custom parse tokens](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format#list-of-all-available-parsing-tokens) would match `UTC` - you can only specify the offset from UTC, not a time-zone code. I suspect you'll need to strip off the `UTC` suffix before parsing.

Comment: `MMMM-DD-YYYY` in `dayjs(utcDate, 'MMMM-DD-YYYY')` is the format string [`dayjs`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) will use to parse the string in `utcDate` which obviously doesn't match the given string.

Comment: @pilchard `dayjs` doesn't care about the end of the string when using a format string for parsing, hence the `.slice(0, -4)` is not necessary.

Comment: @Andreas just tested in Firefox and it fails if the UTC remains, thus the `.slice(0, -4)`

Comment: @pilchard Works like a charm for me and my FF91ESR: https://jsfiddle.net/05zweqgs/

Comment: Issue Resolved when slicing end String as mentioned by @pilchard, Thank You

Comment: @Andreas true with the with the customParseFormat extension, but fails without.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. Credits @pilchard

```
import dayjs from "dayjs"

const utcDate = '2022-01-27 09:23:48 UTC'
const formatedDate = dayjs(utcDate.slice(0, -4)).format("MMMM-DD-YYYY")
```

Comment: Please see the [day.js documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string): "*For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.*". The OP format is not ISO 8601 compliant. Removing the " UTC" part means the string is parsed as local, so no longer UTC. If, by chance, the host system has offset +0 then it still represents the same date and time. However, for any other offset, it now represents a different moment in time.

Comment: Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @RobG, so is it better first we convert utc to local time format and do the formatting using dayjs

Comment: No. To preserve the original date and time, use the [*utc* method](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/utc): `dayjs.utc(utcDate.slice(0, -4))`.